# Import dates from Excel to Numbers?

Tags: ms-office, numbers

I'm trying to move to Numbers instead of Excel for basic sheet stuff, as Excel is a pain in the ass to use on Mac. I'm trying to have some dates to look like dates and apply conditional formatting. The dates in the Excel are like:

```
01.26.2018 12:26:20 PM
01.07.2018 08:03:41 AM
01.13.2018 09:17:45 PM
```

When put this data in Numbers and I choose a column or a cell in Numbers, then switch the data type to Date & Time, nothing happens. I set up some conditional rules, those don't work either. Is there a way I could turn this into date format, so I can apply conditional formatting (like "if day is 5 days from now, be red")? I'm trying this that doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: the date components should be separated by a '/' not by a '.', otherwise all the cell will be interpreted as text (as shown in the lower left corner)

Comment: @GioValerio That helps, thank you! Is there a way I can change this, so it takes dates without me having to find&replace the dots with slashes?

Comment: go back to excel and format your dates using a "custom" format, if the one with the slashes is not among the available. I would say you need something like: m/d/yy h:mm:ss AM/PM;@